# Virus smartphone not going away

Tags: factory-reset, htc-one, antivirus

[image: screenshot]

This keeps coming up on my phone and I have done factory resets thrice already.
My phone is only 3 months old, please help me get rid of this and it seems to infect other phones as well.

I think it was this URL:

```
http://androidmax.mobi/service.customermarket.5206/hwo3ng/back.php?brd=HTC&mod=One%20M9&brw=Chrome%20Mobile&ts=tfx03&var1=68cd67c2-563d-4b02&var2=55b77b9d2a2c4a382546679e&var3=&cs=zno1&voluumdata=vid..00000003-fee6-4323-8000-000000000000__vpid..7b2dc800-430a-11e5-8cee-c3f8afba77aa__caid..d27753a5-480e-4bf9-8fef-29072ffa67a5__rt..R__lid..6056fb29-a6f1-4b3b-82ff-56f1f82adadc__oid1..e43f1ba3-2cda-4f7b-94f8-176b5506c3a3__oid2..10897965-279f-4048-b4e9-d5cec6dc0941__oid3..85de288c-6197-4636-bea1-0dc212cab827__var1..68cd67c2-563d-4b02__var2..55b77b9d2a2c4a382546679e__var8..55599084af7e637526681985__var9..3510__var10..nativeButton__rd..&imp_id=68cd67c2-563d-4b02&app_id=55b77b9d2a2c4a382546679e&idfa=&mac_address=&android_id=&mobile_id=&campaign_id=55599084af7e637526681985&bid=3510&creative_size=nativeButton
```

Comment: Can you give use the URL where you see that message? Also, it's more or less a spam so don't worry much.

Comment: Android Max mobi

Comment: I don't know because I panicked and came away straight away tell me how to find it and I'll get it once u can help to get rid

Comment: I think this question was asked before by you. It's not a virus. Websites use pop ups to redirect you to malware sites or to third party app pages. I've already told you to use Firefox browser and it's add-on AdBlock Plus.

Comment: As @Mani said. There are millions of sites out there that have all kinds of popups trying to scare you and trying to get you to install rogue software. Seeing how you said you have factory reset the device. Is it only when you goto that site or any site? I tried both sites with and without ad blocker and they just seem to endlessly redirect. I am wondering, If they are targeting an exploit that might be in the HTC One? Also when you did the factory resets, did you reinstall all the apps you had before? Cause one of them could be malware and causing this to popup.

Comment: @jer3my I downloaded some eg facebook snapchat 1game and a few anti virus apps. How else will I get rid of it if that app don't work

Answer (score 16):

It is a **Spam** and it has **nothing** to do with your Mobile phone.

There are many websites out there that use these tactics to **persuade users** to click on **malicious link**.

- Please **do not** click on "Remove risks now"
- **Avoid** visiting such links as much as possible
- Also, install [Adblock plus](https://adblockplus.org/android-install)

As of the website, [Scamadviser](http://www.scamadviser.com/) (it reports on the safety of web sites by crawling the web and testing the sites it finds for malware and spam) mentions [here](http://www.scamadviser.com/check-website/androidmax.mobi),

1. It is **58 days old** (as of September 14, 2015) and has a life expectancy of less than a year, which probably means it is a scam website changing its domain every now.
2. The owner of the website is using a service to **hide** their **identity**.
   (Some owners do not wish to receive any spam, so they conceal their identity but many scam sites use this as a method to hide their identify)

Comment: Can I get rid of it or block it I don't understand all the computer terms I feel like selling my phone

Comment: Just install this https://adblockplus.org/android-install

Comment: Simply put,  If you visit those sites in any of the phones, you'll get the same pop-up. It doesn;t mean all those phones are infected. Just install Ad-Block. It will go away.

Comment: It's coming up an app like this could infect my phone will it tho

Comment: Do not panic. They are all ad-s to make you click on their malicious links and make you intsall their fake/spam apps.

Comment: What do I do when I install all this

Comment: I can't open it is there one in the app store

Comment: It is not there in playstore. Install directly from the given link in browser.( Before doing it, Goto settings> Security>Unknown Sources> Allow)

Comment: Ya know this thing on my phone why is it going to others phones in the house

Comment: If something tells you "there's a VIRUS on your Android phone" – be sure it is scam. There are no viruses for Android. You know why penguins and ice-bears can neither be friends nor foes? In nature, they never meet (the bear lives in the north, the penguin in the south). Same with Android and viruses. Stop visiting that zoo (ahem, site), and your issue will be gone.

Comment: @Izzy well said! Yes there is no virus for android. It's based on Linux which is one important reason to have no virus problems. Antivirus apps are just for satisfaction that you are protected from spam.

Comment: Additionally, @manubhargav, you might want to mention the fact that the owner "hides its identity" (btw: very good find with the scamadviser site, which says this – just upvoted your answer). With the context of the other data, this makes your conclusion (which I share) even more likely.

Comment: @manubhargav you might wish to include that with your answer (and we remove these 3 comments then) – cleaner, easier to see – and nobody checks "down here" :)