# Notification for battery virus

Tags: notifications

When I was browsing the internet, a new site opened and it said that I have a virus in my battery and that it will then also infect my sim card and everything else, infected by a recent adoult side that opened while I was watching anime. It was android site so I clicked continue and then it asked for my number so I closed it. I don't know if it's real, and if it is, what should I do?

Comment: Related [SE](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/119319/119358) post

Answer (score 1):

1. there are no viruses for Android. So just by that you can tell it's a fake
2. especially, there are no "battery viruses". Neither is there any "security update" for battery firmware, as often suggested. And even if there were such updates, they are not distributed that way (no system updates inform you via browser popups that they should be applied)
3. websites don't have the facilities to scan your smartphone for that kind of infections. They might be able to tell security holes in your browser (such as "you're using an old version of plugin-X|browser-Y"), but not much more

Knowing these 3 facts, you can rule out 95% of those "warnings" as fakes. If you clicked that anyway, and it asks you for any kind of credentials/serials/system-IDs, that's just fact number 4: No serious updates ever do *that.*