# Removal of the wonderlandads.com pop-up virus

Tags: malware

Would anyone know how I can remove the wonderlandads.com pop-up virus from my Nexus 5 mobile - it appears in my Chrome browser.

While there are many sites dedicated to the manual removal of the virus from PCs, despite several searches I am at a loss to find a suitable alternative solution for Android.

I have installed the free versions of AVG, Avast and Kaspersky to no avail, and I am wary of those sites which suggest SpyHunter, etc as a solution, for a fee. Any help, advice or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: The easiest thing you can do is a factory reset. Not exactly desirable, but _usually_ gets the job done.

Comment: Have you considered using an adblocker?

Comment: Does it happen to some sites, or all sites (including some that are proven safe like Google, or this site)? Does it happen on WiFi/mobile data/both?

Comment: I'd suggest installing Kaspersky. That got it done with all cases I know.

Comment: Hi, I did try the free version of Kapersky but it didn't catch it. Do you know by any chance if the paid-for version works?

Comment: Hi, the site pops up on one particular website - telegraph.co.uk - constantly, but on no others that I can see to date. This always happens on wi-fi, as I am abroad at the moment and don't use data roaming

Comment: I have considered using an adblocker, but in relation to wonderlandads.com any searches always seen to throw up links to Spyhunter, which looks dubious in the extreme. Any other suggestions fur a safe and effective alternative would be much appreciated

Comment: Related [SE post](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/119316/119358)

Comment: @Max400 hmm... if that's the case, I think telegraph.co.uk is the one which is problematic (hosting the malware), and your device is *probably* okay. Based on my research, the malware can attack desktop OS through apps and browser extension, but Android's Chrome doesn't support extension, and you don't seem to have suspicious apps installed on Android (do you?). It's possible that your device's hosts file is modified, but I really doubt currently.

Comment: Meanwhile, can you try using different browser other than Chrome?

Comment: Thanks Andrew, your comments are quite helpful; I will also look at the possibility of removing and reinstalling Chrome (no suspicious apps).

Comment: Take a look at [This](http://superuser.com/questions/1016679/wonderlands-com-annoying-pops-up-none-stop-on-google-chrome-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to successfully identify the cause of wonderland pop ups, this pop up was annoying me for sometime, my PC, two mobiles, a tab was infected and inspite of multiple reset from the scratch didn't work
I realised to look at my router and found a tempered DNS, I validated this with my broadband provider and updated correct one.....this works with me and would work for you as well
Regards
Neeraj

Comment: Thank you Neeraj, that sounds promising. I will look into it and see if I have any luck

Comment: @Neeraj Where was the so called `tempered DNS` added? I get DNS right from my provider and no way to define it manually. would u please explain more?

Answer (score 1):

Neeraj is right i'm also experiencing the same problem and found tempered dns in my router and changed it to dns provided by my isp and malware removed from all my devices but it get changed to malware dns after few hours again. So now i have to change it manually and keep checking. I haven't found a permanent solution for this and checked my systems and devices for dnschanger malware with no luck.

Also in this case only puffin browser will help you on android. In nexus 6 chrome is default browser.

Comment: Where can one find this tempered DNS? please provide more information

Comment: In my WiFi Internet Router's Lan setting there are sub DNS settings. In this there is two fields for primary and secondary DNS, they are getting frequently changed.

Comment: I found solution for my windows computers by using free 14 days trail of hitman pro but my android devices are still affected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove Chrome from your Android device and use default browser. It was ok for me on Galaxy S6 Edge.