# Why does Chrome open links from wonderlandads.com on scrolling?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I have been seeing this problem for a long time in my Android mobile devices and laptop Chrome browser.

When I try to scroll down a page, the browser just hangs for a microsecond and then automatically opens a link (wonderlandads.com/...php)

This wonderlandads tab has random ads in case of laptop, and in case of mobile it says virus detected!

Anybody has any idea how to deal with this?

P.S.:- I googled about overcoming this but did not find any related problem. So I am curious to know whether this issue is related to my Google account and spreads itself on devices where I open my Google account, or is this a Google bug/some sort of virus? I have tried uninstalling all the Chrome extensions.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128957/removal-of-the-wonderlandads-com-pop-up-virus. It seems that the problem is on the website, not on your phone. For laptop, I'm not sure though, but beware not to fall under scam to install the app suggested. It's a known tactic employed by scammer to install worthless "malware fixer".

Comment: Casually speaking, site wants money, thus using ads. :P

Comment: I have noticed that this happens the most when the page has not completely loaded and i start scrolling down.. but i need to resolve this.. Does any know any solution?

Comment: Take a look at [This](http://superuser.com/questions/1016679/wonderlands-com-annoying-pops-up-none-stop-on-google-chrome-in-windows-10)

Comment: @Trix:- I want to add that i am getting this problem majorly on Android phone. I know many of the problems are solved by un-install and re-install of OS but i dont think that this is the best solution and i go for this only in the extreme cases (this does not seem to be an extreme case for now ).. have tried reinstalling chrome on phone though, no luck..