# Anitivirus and antimalware apps not working on malicious ads shown during the usage of Times of India app

Tags: malware

I have a Redmi 2 Prime phone running Android 4.4.4. I have a news app named Times of India in which if I read some articles, suddenly, an ad popup appears. And these ads seem to be totally fake and malicious. Ads like "your phone has slowed down" or "your phone has virus". They take up the whole space, so it's like a hijack.

There was this same problem, only more severe, in my last phone. Now I have changed the phone altogether, but it seems the problem have crept back in somehow.

I have installed all sorts of antivirus and anti-malware apps with no avail.

How do I get rid of the issue?

Comment: I'll also suggest trying avast and Kaspersky if you already haven't. You should find the app that creates such ads and delete it.

Comment: Related [AndroidSE post](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/119316/119358)

Comment: Does this happen only when you use the news app? Is it 3rd-party app? Could we know the name of the app?

Comment: The app is Times of India

Answer (score 2):

If the problem persists on two different devices but within the same application, I would suspect that the application *is* the problem. Looking at the [Times of India app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.toi.reader.activities), the first sign is the "Mature 17+" rating, which is suspicious for a news app. The second is the ridiculous list of permissions for this app:

```
Version 3.8.1 can access:
Device & app history
read sensitive log data
Identity
find accounts on the device
Contacts
find accounts on the device
Location
precise location (GPS and network-based)
approximate location (network-based)
SMS
read your text messages (SMS or MMS)
Phone
read phone status and identity
Photos/Media/Files
modify or delete the contents of your USB storage
read the contents of your USB storage
Storage
modify or delete the contents of your USB storage
read the contents of your USB storage
Wi-Fi connection information
view Wi-Fi connections
Device ID & call information
read phone status and identity
Other
receive data from Internet
full network access
view network connections
read Google service configuration
prevent device from sleeping
control vibration
```

Finally, if you look at the reviews for the app, most of the negative reviews say there are a lot of very obtrusive ads (while a lot of the positive reviews are spam not even related to the app).

I would suggest either finding another news source (like accessing a respectable newspaper through the mobile browser) or continue using the Times of India app and live with the fact that those ads make the app free to use.

Comment: It's rated 3+ on my side, though in my opinion, news app having rated for 17+ (or at least PG) is understandable, depending on the contents (sometimes political issues, or entertainment is not family-friendly). But I agree with the rest of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get in safe mode (*google it for your phone*)

Then go to applications see in all applications and uninstall applications that are uninstallable

Go check again your phone might be fine and you can also try *`Adaway`*

Comment: I had tried this in my previous phone. It didn't work. I uninstalled as many as I could, but browser pages would still redirect randomly. Now that is not happening in my new phone. But it has started in this one app.

Comment: I think it is inbuilt in that app?